# timestamps microsecond precision is reset to 000 when kafka deserializes data to create sql insert (?)

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, timestamp-with-timezone, fastavro

Using avro schema for data; have a field for timestamp named 'time'
and its like this:

> ```
>      {"name": "time", "type":
>    {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-micros"}},
> ```

The timestamp-micros could alternatively be timestamp-millis but
I want microseconds included that's why I chose this.

What is passed on here is :

> {'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 10, 6, 52, 53, 511281, tzinfo=)}

The problem is when this is deserialized I get something like

> 2022, 1, 10, 6, 52, 53, 511000
> inserted into the database. This is shaving off the micros.
> What is this related to?

What this is matched with

Comment: What is the datatype of the timestamp column as per the create table statement?